# Workbook.Close is closing two workbooks

Tags: c#, vba, vsto

I have a C# application that uses VSTO to interact with Excel.

I have an issue that when I try to close the current workbook it also closes the previous workbook that was open.  If the current workbook is the only one that exists, then it crashes Excel.  The (very simple code) is as follows:

```
        // If saving the workbook via a prompt when closing the workbook
        // Excel decides an infinite loop to this event would be a good idea.
        // We therefore need to explicitly close the workbook once saved.
        if (workbookClosing)
        {
           wb.Application.EnableEvents = true;
           wb.Close();

           workbookClosing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            wb.Application.EnableEvents = true;
        }
```

My initial thought was that wb was somehow pointing at two workbooks. The code only runs once, and wb is only assigned once.

I'm hoping that somebody has encountered this before.

Comment: Sounds like wb.Close calls the event that calls wb.Close...can you show where this code is? Which event

Comment: Should your first `wb.Application.EnableEvents = true` be `wb.Application.EnableEvents = false`?